# How to pip install source or binary distribution from GitHub without checkout

Tags: python, github, pip

When pip installing via a git URI, it will run git clone. However, I want to avoid cloning the repository because the repository is much larger than just the source distribution. I rather install the source (`mypkg.tar.gz`) or binary (`mypkg.whl`) distribution directly from release files.

Answer (score 1):

The releases are available to install using HTTPS URL. You'll have to know the naming scheme of their releases beforehand. For example, the numpy GitHub release scheme is used like so:

```
pip install https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases/download/vx.y.z/numpy-x.y.z.tar.gz
```

### Advantages/Disadvantages:

Compared to using the git URI,

- Can only specify a single version. Cannot specify a range of version
- Cannot specify the latest package without a version-independent naming scheme (e.g., `numpy.tar.gz`)
- Faster downloads if the release is smaller than the repository.
- Skip build if the release file is a binary distribution (.whl) wasn't in the repository.